# Git pull multiple local repositories with script (ruby?)

Tags: ruby, macos, git, github, repository

I have ~30 git repositories cloned from github that I use for web/ruby/javascript development. Is it possible to bulk update all of them with a script?

I have everything pretty organized (folder structure):

```
- Workspace
  - Android
  - Chrome
  - GitClones
    - Bootstrap
    ~ etc...30 some repositories
  - iPhone
  - osx
  - WebDev
```

I have a ruby script to clone repositories with `octokit`, but are there any suggestions on how to do git pull (overwriting/rebasing local) in all the repositories under `GitClones`?

Normally I would just do a pull whenever I was about to use that repo, but I am going to a place where internet connectivity is only going to be available sometimes. So I would like to update everything I can while I have internet.

Thanks! (Running osx 10.8.2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you must do it in Ruby, here's a quick and dirty script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

Dir.entries('./').select do |entry|
  next if %w{. .. ,,}.include? entry
  if File.directory? File.join('./', entry)
    cmd = "cd #{entry} && git pull"
    `#{cmd}`
  end
end
```

Don't forget to chmod +x the file you copy this into and ensure it's in your GitClones directory.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, stackoverflow to the rescue again!

Answer (score 4):

Sure, but why use ruby when shell will suffice?

```
function update_all() {
  for dir in GitClones/*; do 
    cd "$dir" && git pull
  done
}
```

Comment: I've become fond of ruby and I figured if most of my scripts were going to be written in ruby I might as well stick with it. But shell works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change beginning of glob to taste.  This does two useful things:

1. It only git pull when it contains .git subdir
2. It skips dot (.) dirs since no one has git repos which start with a dot.

Enjoy

```
# Assumes run from Workspace
Dir['GitClones/[^.]*'].select {|e| File.directory? e }.each do |e|
  Dir.chdir(e) { `git pull` } if File.exist? File.join(e, '.git')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Revised to provider better output and be OS agnostic. This one cleans local changes, and updates code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pp'

# no stdout buffering
STDOUT.sync = true

# checks for windows/unix for chaining commands
OS_COMMAND_CHAIN = RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/ ? "&" : ";"

Dir.entries('.').select do |entry|
  next if %w{. .. ,,}.include? entry
  if File.directory? File.join('.', entry)
    if File.directory? File.join('.', entry, '.git')
      full_path = "#{Dir.pwd}/#{entry}"
      git_dir = "--git-dir=#{full_path}/.git --work-tree=#{full_path}"
      puts "\nUPDATING '#{full_path}' \n\n"
      puts `git #{git_dir} clean -f #{OS_COMMAND_CHAIN} git #{git_dir} checkout . #{OS_COMMAND_CHAIN} git #{git_dir} pull` 
    end
  end
end
```